# How to set the number of ports for ConfigNode and DataNode in cluster of Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I tried to upgrade Apache IoTDB to Version 1.0.1, seems like for `dn_target_config_node_list`
only one IP port can be filled, so I cannot set `dn_target_config_node_list = 172.27.22.157:10710,172.27.22.158:10710` in V1.0.1? If only one port can be set, if the seed configure went down, will the whole cluster went down?

For datanode configuration, I tried to set only one datanode last time, and when I turned off the configured ip service, the cluster went down. Do I need to set multiple corresponding configurations to maintain the cluster operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, ConfigNode can only configure one IP port in Apache IoTDB. If you configure one port, the cluster will broadcast and know all surviving ConfigNode lists. If you start 3 ConfigNodes, it will not affect cluster function if any of them went wrong.
This configuration of DataNode, however, can set to be multiple ports. If you have configured 3 ConfigNodes, as long as the DataNode can be connected to IoTDB server when it is started for the first time, then the DataNode will automatically save the endpoints of the three ConfigNodes, so cluster function will not be affected if any of them went wrong.